# Sacar datos de arreglo en CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de sacar los datos de un arreglo.

```html
$data = array();
$data["usuario_pantallas"] = $this->usuario_pantalla->usuario_pantalla();
print_r($data);
```

Y cuando lo imprimo esto es lo que obtengo

```html
Array ( [usuario_pantallas] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_pantalla] => 1 [id_tipo_usuario] => 1 ) ) )
```

Como guardo por separado en una variable el id_pantalla y el id_tipo_usuario

Comment: Siempre va a ser un usuario el que traeria el array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente 1-mandalos a llamar de forma separada, 2-separa el array obtenido en un foreach

1
Controller

```
$data           = array(
                       'id_pantallas'   = $this->usuario_pantalla->get_usuario_pantalla('id_pantallas'),
                       'id_tipo_usuario'= $this->usuario_pantalla->get_usuario_pantalla('id_tipo_usuario')
                       );
var_dump($data);
```

modelo

```
function get_usuario_pantalla ( $opt ){
    $this->db->select($opt);
    return $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
}
```

2

```
$usuario_pantallas = $this->usuario_pantalla->usuario_pantalla();

foreach($usuario_pantallas as $item){
    $id_pantallas[]    = $item->id_pantallas;
    $id_tipo_usuario[] = $item->id_tipo_usuario;
}

$data = array(
              'id_pantallas'       => $id_pantallas,
              'id_tipo_usuario'    => $id_tipo_usuario
           );
var_dump($data);
```